# Python ECDH with Cryptography Problem Public Key

Tags: python, elliptic-curve, python-cryptography

Currently I started working with the cryptography framework on python. I'm trying to build a SSH Suit by my own but I ran into some problem with the library. I'm trying to build my own Elliptic Curve Key Exchange Init Packet (with scapy).

I'm trying to do an Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman key exchange with the curve secp256r1. I'm able to generate the key-pair on my client with out any problem. But after I created the public key object im kinda confused how to get the 32-byte public key for exchange via network packets.

my code so far (which doesn't work for me):
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serilization

curve = SECP256R1()
peer_private_key = ec.generate_private_key(curve)
peer_public_key = peer_private_key.public_key()

peer_public_pkt = peer_public_key.public_bytes(encoding=serilization.Encoding.DER, format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)
```

But this peer_public_pkt is not 32 Byte long.

Another Problem is when i get like an ECDH Public Key Value via Scapy or Wireshark from a Server via Network i cant translate the value back with

```
srv_public_key = ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(curve, data_from_wireshark)
```

I think I'm missing some crucial steps here but I looked at the  documentation for two hours and into some older examples on different sites but I can't find help (or see the solution).

Hopefully you can help me :). If something about my problem is not clear just ask.

Comment: Have you tried base32 encoding your key for network translation?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish can you give me an example of what you mean? im not really sure how to do this in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point` takes compressed/uncompressed points. You can obtain those from `public_bytes` via a format of `PublicFormat.CompressedPoint` and format of `Encoding.X962`. SubjectPublicKeyInfo DER serialization is an ASN.1 format with additional structure.

Your assumption of 32 bytes on a secp256r1 key is also incorrect, as a compressed public point adds one byte defining the sign for unambiguous point reconstruction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That helped me. But do you know if the encoding and format is somehow standartised by the curve itself or by the algorith that uses it?

Comment: I dont really understand what the actuall Public Key Q_S (which is transmitted in an Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman Init) is in the SSH protocol. Is it just an compressed point which got cut off its first byte? @Paul Kehrer

Comment: RFC 5656 may be helpful in understanding how SSH does this.

Comment: I read the rfc already but its just not clear for me how to use this octet-string conversion with cryptography